# PhP Unable to load dynamic library ds.so

Tags: queue, php-7, pecl

I want to use [Php queues](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.ds.php) and i have insatalled the Php-DS extension. I used PECL as shown [here](https://github.com/php-ds/extension). When i load my project i get the following error:

```
Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/ds.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/ds.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce
```

What have i done wrong? Am using PHP 7 and Zorin OS.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, in PHP 7.4. 

If I add `extension=json` to my php.ini, I get this warning: `PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`. And when I actually load the page, I get this exception: `Module 'json' already loaded.`

I tried changing the prioority settings:

* /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/json.ini: priority=20
* /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/ds.ini: priority=30

No joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoDB extension had a problem just like this. You have to make sure that the json extension is pulled in before it, and then it would be OK.

If you are adding this extension in via a directory with named/numbered .ini files, make sure that the json-referring file is listed first alphanumerically so it would be found and included first.  If there are just a list of extensions in the main php.ini file, again, make sure the `json.so` is listed ahead of `ds.so`